# Why is this map continuous?(cofibration)

Tags: functions, algebraic-topology

Thank you for watching this question! I'm reading the book "Algebraic Topology from a Homotopical Viewpoint". On p.94, there is the following theorem.

4.1.6 Theorem. 
Let $X$ be normal and let $A\subset X$ be closed. Then the following are equivalent.

(a)The inclusion $A \rightarrow X$ is a cofibration.

(b)There exists a homotopy $D:X\times I \rightarrow X$ and a function $ \phi :X\rightarrow I$ such that $A\subset \phi^{-1}(0) $ and 
$$ D(x,0)=x ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(x\in X)\\ D(a,t)=a~~~~~~~~~~ (a\in A,t\in I) \\ D(x,t)\in A ~~~~~(x\in X,t>\phi (x))$$

(c)The subset $A$ is a strong deformation retract of a neighborhood $V$ in $X$, and there exists $\psi :X\rightarrow I$ such that $A=\psi ^{-1}(0)$ and $\psi |{X-V}=1 $.

The proof of (b)$\Rightarrow $(c) is the following.

(pf)Given $D$ and $\phi$ we define $V=\phi ^{-1}[0,1)$. Then $V$ is a neighborhood of $A$ in $X$. Moreover, $A$ is a strong deformation retract of $V$ , since if we define $H:V\times I\rightarrow X $ as $D|{V\times I}$,then $H$ satisfies the conditions $A$ is strong deformation retract of $V$. We then define $\psi :X\rightarrow I$ by
$$ \psi(x)=\inf\{t\in I|D(x,t)\in A\} $$

Question:Why is the function $\psi$ continuous? And I can't understand this $\psi $ satisfies the condition $A=\psi^{-1}(0)$. If $\phi (x)=1$, there is no $t \in I$ satisfies the condition $t > \phi (x)$,I think. What is the infimum of empty set?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange. Learn more about our community: https://math.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

Just to give a quick answer to the question of why a particular function is continuous, the book [Topology and Groupoids](http://groupoids.org.uk/topgpds.html) (T&G) has in this context the following proposition:

**7.3.10** Let $\phi: X \times C \to \mathbb R$ be a map where $C$ is compact. Define $w: X \to \mathbb R$ by $x \mapsto \sup _{c \in C} \phi(x,c)$. Then $w$ is well defined and continuous.

This source might help with your other questions.

I recall pointing out to Dieter Puppe in the early 1960s at Liverpool that lots of his results on pointed spaces in his well known paper on "Homotopie mengen...." seemed to generalise to replacing a point by a closed cofibration; this resulted in his 1967 paper on "...Erweiterung von Homotopien". This theme is pursued in T&G, for example to obtain operations of fundamental groupoids on certain homotopy sets.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I'll check the book!